# My husband and I want to visit my sister in Canada

Tags: usa, canada, borders

My husband and I on July 14, 2020 fly from Texas to Portland Maine, rent a car to travel to Ste Christine, Quebec, Canada to visit sister returning July 23, 2020.

Will we be able to cross the border then?

Comment: Can you give some more info on your documents, please? Do you hold a USA/Canadian  visa/citizenship?

Comment: @NateEldredge Personally, I think this is asking about documentation, not COVID restrictions

Comment: Interestingly, if said sister lives in Canada, they would have or be able to acquire quite easily information on crossing the US/Canadian border. Pre-pandemic, I only needed my passport at the border crossing. Previously, I only needed to have my state drivers license or ID. Back then, they even let the adolescents from our youth group cross without ID if they were in possession of a notarized parental consent. The current policies will be a lot more fluid with the current pandemic. Check with the state departments of each country.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was born in Canada and I well remember not needing any documentation to travel between small communities in northern Maine and western New Brunswick. According to what I read today on current Canada visitor policy immediate family, sisters don’t qualify, can visit for a minimum 15 days! However, I do have dual citizenship so quite possibly I can visit but doubt that my husband can. We have American passports. Hopefully the restrictions will relax soon.